# android: force close when try sqlite database on service

Tags: android, sqlite, service

i want to getRawCount from sqlite database in service, but i getting error.

Here's my code on service class :

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    database_center helper = null;
    Cursor cursor;

    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from list", null);
    int rawCount = cursor.getCount();

    Toast.makeText(this, "The Service Started. Count  "+rawCount, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Log Cat:

`08-12 22:47:51.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13053): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-12 22:47:51.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13053): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.belService.theService@416d5818 with Intent { cmp=com.example.belService/.theService }: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-12 22:47:51.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13053):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2575)
08-12 22:47:51.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13053):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:143)
08-12 22:47:51.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13053):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1338)
08-12 22:47:51.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13053):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-12 22:47:51.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13053):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-12 22:47:51.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13053):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4963)
08-12 22:47:51.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13053):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 22:47:51.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13053):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-12 22:47:51.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13053):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
08-12 22:47:51.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13053):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
08-12 22:47:51.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13053):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-12 22:47:51.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13053): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-12 22:47:51.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13053):    at com.example.belService.theService.onStartCommand(theService.java:48)
08-12 22:47:51.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13053):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2558)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
database_center helper = null;
Cursor cursor;

SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
```

The variable helper is initialized to null in line 1 and never changed afterwards; obviously line 3 will give null exception, since you called method `getReadableDatabase()` on a null object.